# on close listener for android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Tags: java, android

I have a menu in my activity with this code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

And an oncreatoptionsmenu:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onClose",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            show_all_drugs();
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

But on close listener not working. Whats problem? And how can I work with my search view in activity's oncreate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hello",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    show_all_drugs();
    return true;
}
```